# How do I allow a field to be undefined while disallowing type coercion using Yup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, validation, yup

I'm trying to validate an object's field using yup.

These are my requirements:

1. The field should either be a string or undefined.
2. If it is undefined, it should be given a default value.
3. If it is a value of some other type, it should not be coerced into a string. Instead, it should be incompatible and should result in an error.

I've tried the following so far:

A. The following schema does not prevent type coercion. e.g. when the value is a number, it passes the validation. However, I want it to fail the validation.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  myField: yup.string().default('myDefaultString')
});
```

B. The following schema prevents type coercion, but it fails when I pass an undefined value. I actually want the value to be 'myDefaultString' if an undefined value is given.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  myField: yup.string().strict(true).default('myDefaultString')
});
```

C. The following schema has the same result as option B.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  myField: yup.string().strict(true).notRequired().default('myDefaultString')
});
```

D. Use `strict: true` as part of the options when using `validateSync` method to validate the schema. Again, this has the same result as B.

Would appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that you can extend the yup string as follows:

```
class StrictString extends yup.string {
  constructor() {
    super();
    transforms = []; // remove the default type coercion transforms
  }
}
```

And then, replace `StrictString()` with `yup.string()`.
This will fit the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Yup is capable of satisfying all three of your requirements using `yup.lazy`* which creates a schema at validation/cast time. It's also highly readable as it utilizes an easy to follow `switch` statement.

The following evaluates a value based on your conditions:

```
const StringOrUndefinedSchema = yup.lazy((value) => {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'undefined':
      return yup.string().default('myDefaultString');
    case 'string':
      return yup.string().strict();
    default:
      throw new yup.ValidationError("Value must be a string or `undefined`"); 
  }
});
```

It can then be used anywhere, including an object's field as in your example:

```
const ObjectWithFieldSchema = yup.object({
  myField: StringOrUndefinedSchema,
});
```

Putting it all together:

```
const yup = require("yup");

const StringOrUndefinedSchema = yup.lazy((value) => {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'undefined':
      return yup.string().default('myDefaultString');
    case 'string':
      return yup.string();
    default:
      throw new yup.ValidationError("Value must be a string or `undefined`"); 
  }
});

const ObjectWithFieldSchema = yup.object({
  myField: StringOrUndefinedSchema,
});

const iWillDefault = await ObjectWithFieldSchema.validate({ });
const iWillBeStrict = await ObjectWithFieldSchema.validate({ myField: "I am a string" });

console.log(iWillDefault); // { myField: "myDefaultString" }
console.log(iWillBeStrict); // { myField: "I am a string" }
```

View the previous example code on RunKit here: https://runkit.com/joematune/6138658a9113f00008292564

- Yup.lazy - https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuplazyvalue-any--schema-lazy